# Connecting to SOTAMAS90 ODBC?

Tags: vb.net, odbc, connection-string

How do I connect to Mas90's file using their ODBC that they setup - SOTAMAS90? how do I do this in vb.net ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [found this as an example](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=70589) - I have not tried it myself to know 100% sure if it works or not, nor do I profess myself as a vb.net programmer but it's at least something to try...

```
Imports System.Data
Imports Microsoft.Data.Odbc

' Database Connection
Public dbConn As OdbcConnection = Nothing
Public dbCmnd As OdbcCommand
Public dbReader As OdbcDataReader
Public dbConnStr As String
Public dbError As Exception

' Connect to MAS90 using ODBC; dbError stores the
' exception if any
Sub connectToDatabase(ByVal company As String, ByVal uid As String, ByVal pwd As String)

    Dim dsn As String = "SOTAMAS90"
    Dim timeout As String = "360"

    ' Build the connection string
    dbConnStr = "DSN=" + dsn + _
            ";Directory=M:\MAS90" + _
            ";Prefix=M:\MAS90\soa\" + _
            ";ViewDLL=M:\MAS90\Home\" + _
            ";SERVER=NotTheServer" + _
            ";Company=" + company + _
            ";UID=" + uid + ";PWD=" + pwd + ";"

    ' Connect if not already
    If (dbConn Is Nothing) Then
        Try
            dbConn = New OdbcConnection(dbConnStr)
            dbConn.ConnectionTimeout = timeout
            dbConn.Open()
            dbError = Nothing
        Catch ex As Exception
            dbError = ex
            dbConn = Nothing
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```